# Using Excel File in SQL Query Or Batch Select in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, database, ms-access

I am using ms access database to do some queries at my job. I couldn't find a way to do a bulk select query within this table.

I have a "tblData" table with about 2 million rows. The table looks like this:

| ID | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jone Doe | 555555555 |
| 2 | Name2 | 555555555 |
| 3 | Name3 | 555555555 |
| 4 | Name4 | 555555555 |

I have an excel file containing ID of about 800 thousand lines and I am trying to print the name and phone number next to the id's in this excel file. I will use Vba and ADO for this.

What is the easiest way?

The first method I tried was to put the IDs in an array in Excel and use the IN operator in SQL. It took about 5 minutes when I tried with 5000 id. When I tried with more ids, I got an error. I think the reason for the error is that the query string is too long.

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE ID IN (" & Join(myBatchLocalList, ", ") & ")"

'myBatchLocalList is array. It include IDs from local excel file.
```

Another way I can think of is to select all the data, loop it in VBA and print out the matches. However, since the data is 2 million rows, I used ADODB and get an out of memory warning.

There are 2 methods I want try but I can't succeed.

1. INNER JOIN: First get customer numbers from excel, then query from DB and join 2 tables. However, I do not know whether data is imported from Excel in a query. Like this:

```
select Local.Id, T.Name, T.Phone     
from (select ID from "Column A from xlsx file." ) Local
inner join (select ID, Name, Phone from tblData ) T
on T.ID = Local.ID
```

2. INSERT INTO: First, loading the entire list in Excel into a table named tblTemp in the DB with INSERT INTO, then pulling tblTemp again with another query and getting the data from the tblData table using LEFT JOIN. However, I don't know how to implement the insert into part. Like this:

```
DELETE FROM tblTemp;

INSERT INTO tblTemp VALUES "bulk from Excel Files"

SELECT ID, tblData.Name, tblData.Phone 
FROM tblTemp 
LEFT JOIN tblData on tblTemp.ID = tblData.ID
```

I hope I was able to explain clearly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Build a query to join the two tables (Excel one would be linked) - then use `CopyFromRecordset` method on the Excel Range

Comment: As @dbmitch outlines, in Access link the EXCEL table via ODBC or Office interfaces.  Now it is available as a regular table in Access.  Make sure you have an index on ID in tblData, then build a query that Left Outer Joins the Excel table to the tblData table, run it and you're done.  No need for VBA at all.

Comment: Yes. It is work but my query list changeable and i don't want access as linked table, i want use client/front-end as vba.  I can add 800 thousand rows of data to the tbltemp file in 10 seconds with ADODBCommand:
"insert into tblTemp select * from [test5.txt] in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\' 'Text;HDR=Yes'". I need this string with Excel.